# select a sample of all rows but only two countries with the highest sales

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to prepare a sample with slice_max of dplyr by selecting all rows but only of two countries with the highest sum(sales). I need to sum(sales) to know which country has higher sales. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    country = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
    sales   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
  )

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate( s = sum(sales)) %>% 
  slice_max(s, n=2)
```

Edit. Altering sales with NA raises the difficulty level:

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    country = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
    sales   = c(1, 1, NA, 4, 3)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

*Edited solution & data*

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    country = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    sales   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
  )

df1 %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(tot_sales = sum(sales, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  chop( sales) %>%
  slice_max(tot_sales, n = 2) %>%
  unchop(sales)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   country tot_sales sales
#>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1       3         4     3
#> 2       3         4     1
#> 3       2         3     1
#> 4       2         3     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

*previous incorrect solution*

I think you may have just been missing the `ungroup()`

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    country = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
    sales   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
  )


df1 %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(tot_sales = sum(sales)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  top_n(2, tot_sales)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   country sales tot_sales
#>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1       2     1         3
#> 2       2     2         3
#> 3       3     3         3
```

Looks like top_n has been superseded by `slice_max`:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(tot_sales = sum(sales)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_max(n = 2, tot_sales)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I would like to stick to slice_max function since top_n is going to obsolate. Can you please edit it?

Comment: No, it does not work. Why does it return a tibble, and not a modified df1? df1 stays the same as in the beginning. I want it trimmed to only 2 counties.

Comment: I got it. Should be `df1 <- df1 %>%  group_by(country) `...

Comment: dplyr tends to return tibbles, which are pretty much the same as data.frames. You can assign the output to df1 with  `df1<-` , though it is generally bad practice to change the original data.

Comment: Sorry, I edited your answer. Reverse it, if you wish.

Comment: Are you sure the ungroup() should be before the slice_max?

Comment: The data was ambiguous for the above previous solution.  I've adjusted the data & posted a solution that should work.

Comment: There is a problem. `sales = c(1, 1, NA, 4, 3)` if there is NA in sales we do not get the expected results. `mutate(tot_sales = sum(sales, na.rm = TRUE))` will not fix it.

Comment: na.rm =T added. Try again.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I let this answer mature a little before I accepting it. It looks too heavy. Six steps in dplyr to accomplish such a simple task. With a command chop that I never heard of? I suspect there could be a lighter way.